# Do subtraction of last two rows of gridview using c#.net

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, gridview

I have a gridview on my page I am binding data from table (Mysql database) to it. Also gridview has AutoGenerateColumns property to 'true'. Now the gridview have all the columns autogenerated and I have last 2 rows named 'Total' & 'HeadCount'. I want to subtract 'HeadCount' from 'Total'. And add new row 'Final Total' to the grid.
How can I do this? Should I do it database side? If so How? Should I do it application c# code side? If so How?
Please help me out if anyone has an answer for this. Thanks..!

Code:

```
ds=getAllStudents();
gridStuds.DataSource=ds;
gridStuds.DataBind();
```

Comment: Post here What you have tried?

Comment: How do you bind your data? Do you first get them in a datatable and then pass the datatable as datasource to the gridview? Also please post your code. It's quite difficult to help otherwise.

Comment: I have one method getStudents() that returns me dataset.And that dataset I am binding to grid.Now next I am have to do subtraction of last rows named 'Total' and 'Headcount' and put the result to new row at last to gridview.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

do it as code below

```
DataColumn totalColumn = new DataColumn();
totalColumn.ColumnName = "FinalTotal";
totalColumn.DataType = typeof (int);
totalColumn.DefaultValue = 0;
dtSourceTable.Columns.Add(totalColumn);

foreach (DataRow row in dtSourceTable.Rows)
{
    row["FinalTotal"] = Convert.ToInt32
       (row["HeadCount"]) - Convert.ToInt32(row["Total"]);
}
```